# Postscript resource files: How to pass function parameters?

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, resource-files

I have some postscript resource files for drawing objects (flaggs) in any postscript file (inspired from Terry Burton's [postscriptbarcode](https://code.google.com/p/postscriptbarcode/)).

The files for drawing the flaggs are in subfolder Flaggs (without extension .ps), together with some helper files, 
especially `sethexcolor`, defining a function `sethexcolor`, to set RGB color from a hexstring.

I have a file `sample.ps` above the subfolder Flaggs with code:

```
100 600 moveto
100 /square /Flaggs findresource exec   % draw a square of size 100
showpage
```

File `square` has code:

```
1 dict
dup /sethexcolor dup /Flaggs findresource put
begin
/square {
    /size exch def
    currentpoint translate
    /red (ff0000) def
    red sethexcolor
    % 1 0 0 setrgbcolor
} bind def
/square dup load /Flaggs defineresource pop
end
```

I'm working in Windows 7 with ghostscript 9.10. 
Ghostscript is called with command line parameter `-P` to look for files in current folder first. 
(Search path can be seen with gswin32c [-P] -h in command shell). Normally this works fine (e.g. with postscriptbarcode, see above).

But here it doesn't work: Starting `sample.ps`, I get an error message:

```
Error: /undefined in sethexcolor
Operand stack:
   (ff0000)
```

(After setting RGB color with `1 0 0 setrgbcolor`, it works.)

If I change `red sethexcolor` to `red /sethexcolor` or `red //sethexcolor`, there's no error message, and a square is drawn - 
but in black, not in red.

What's wrong with this postscript code? 
Why can't function `square` call function `sethexcolor` in the same folder?

Wolfgang

Comment: For an explanation of how to accept an answer, see
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
red //sethexcolor exec
```

Using an immediate name (with `//`) will load the current definition while the `square` procedure body is being constructed. Since `sethexcolor` is (presumably) a procedure, you must explicitly `exec` it in order to execute.